# How to specify custom return Url after receiving the token or on failure?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have the following setup:

- I'm having an Angular frontend and Spring-Boot backend
- Users are logging in to my backend via normal Form login
- I'm integrating a third party API which needs oauth2 authentication, so Users need to grant permissions to my App so I can load data on their behalf from that third party
- I configured `oauth2Client()` in my `HttpSecurity` config to enable oauth2

What currently happens is:

1. The frontend is calling an endpoint to get data from the third party, lets say `/api/get-library` which tries to access a protected resource at the third party.
2. This will lead to a `401` from the third party and trigger the oauth flow in Spring
3. The User is redirected to the third party to grant permissions to my App
4. After granting permissions the User is first redirected to the Url I specified as `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.foobar.redirect-uri`
5. Spring Boot then retrieves the token and stores it for my Principal
6. After that Spring Boot **redirects to the original url** `/api/get-library`
7. But this is just some `RestController` so the User is presented with some JSON data in the Browser

So point 6 is my problem. I don't want that the User is in the end redirected to some API endpoint, I want him to be redirected to a page of my Angular application.

A similar problem arises if the user rejects the permission grant. Then the user is redirected to `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.foobar.redirect-uri` with an query param `?error=true`. Also in this case I want a redirect to my Angular application.

Initially I thought I could also configure `oauth2Login()` which has an `failureHandler` and `successHandler`, but those aren't called in my case, since I'm not doing a Login here.

So can somebody help me? How can I configure my own redirects for `oauth2Client`? In case of success, and on failure? What are relevant Beans here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

The main Spring class to check is `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter`. This Filter is invoked when the user granted/rejected the permissions at the OAuth Provider.

Unfortunately there is no way to configure a custom redirect Url for this Filter, so I implemented a hacky solution:

1. I copied the implementation of `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` to an own class and extended it with 2 parameters: success and error return Url. I then used those Urls in the `processAuthorizationResponse` Method to redirect to my Urls
2. I then put my own`AppOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` before the Spring Filter in the `HttpSecurityConfig`, so it is used instead of the Spring version
3. In my Angular App I'm storing the exact location in the App before calling an Endpoint that potentially requires OAuth authentication. So when the User agent returns to the Angular App I can navigate back to the origin location.

It feels very hacky, so if somebody comes up with a better solution I'd be glad to hear it. :-)

Some Code snippets for Spring:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.addFilterBefore(oAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter(), OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.class);
        ...
    }

    @Bean @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AppOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter oAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter() throws Exception {
        return new AppOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter(
                clientRegistrationRepository,
                oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository,
                authenticationManagerBean(),
                oauthSuccessRedirectUrl,
                oauthErrorRedirectUrl);
    }
```